# Bad PostgreSQL Request with AND/OR Operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is something wrong in my postresql request ?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(email) FROM data 
WHERE email != '' AND gender='mme' OR gender='mlle' 
AND yearofbirth BETWEEN 1973 AND 2003
```

Can we put as 'AND' and 'OR' operator as we want ?
Because the statement 'AND yearofbirth BETWEEN 2003 AND 1973' is not working, the request result is the result of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(email) FROM data 
WHERE email != '' AND gender='mme' OR gender='mlle'
```

...

Same issue for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(email) FROM data 
WHERE email != '' AND gender='mme' OR gender='mlle' 
AND yearofbirth < 2003 AND yearofbirth > 1973
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Use parenthesis. Imagine OR is '+' and AND is '.', writing (a+b).c is not equivalent to write a + b.c !

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(email) 
     FROM data WHERE email != '' AND  ( gender='mme' OR gender='mlle') AND 
         yearofbirth BETWEEN 1973 AND 2003
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` is clearly not needed in this case.  Your query is phrased as an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`, so it is only going to return one row.  I suspect that you really want `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT)`, a different beast altogether.

I'm also not sure what you intend in the `WHERE` clause.  I suspect this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email)
FROM data 
WHERE email <> '' AND
      (gender IN 'mme', 'mlle') AND 
      yearofbirth BETWEEN 1973 AND 2003;
```

Although without parentheses, you have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email)
FROM data 
WHERE (email <> '' AND gender = 'mme') OR
      (gender = 'mlle' AND yearofbirth BETWEEN 1973 AND 2003);
```